# Dynamically insert/switch stylesheet in an iframe (iframe source hosted on my domain)

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I was wondering if there is a simple solution to switch stylesheets on a page in an iframe.  Basically, this is what I have in mind>

```
<iframe name="iframe" src="page on my domain.html"></iframe>

<form id="switcher">
  <input type="button" value="Switch to style 1" />
  <input type="button" value="Switch to style 2" />
  <input type="button" value="Switch to style 3" />
</form>
```

Comment: You didn't show the iframe source. Depending on how your stylesheet is implemented, your code will look different (inline vs link).

Comment: What I want to do is add another stylesheet declaration to the page in the iframe, showing different 'skins' of the same structured page.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
<iframe id="iframe" name="iframe" src="test.html"></iframe>
<form id="switcher">
  <input type="button" value="Switch to style 1" onclick="var a=document.getElementById('iframe').contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('link');a=a[0];a.href='path/to/some.css';" />
  <input type="button" value="Switch to style 2" />
  <input type="button" value="Switch to style 3" />
</form>
```

Comment: @user1628131 This will work if you put id="iframe" on your iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming jQuery is installed:

http://www.kelvinluck.com/2009/07/jquery-styleswitch-now-with-toggle/

Okay, it is really much easier... I used the css zen garden to get styled pages for this test:

for your HTML:

```
<iframe name="iframe" 
   id="iframetarget" 
   src="http://www.csszengarden.com/" 
   width=400 
   height=400>
</iframe>

<form id="switcher">
  <input type="button" id="v1" value="Switch to style 1" />
  <input type="button" id="v2" value="Switch to style 2" />
  <input type="button" id="v3" value="Switch to style 3" />
</form>​
```

And for your jQuery:

```
$('#v1').click(function() {
    $('#iframetarget').prop({
        src: 'http://www.csszengarden.com/?cssfile=/213/213.css&amp;page=0'
    });
});
$('#v2').click(function() {
    $('#iframetarget').prop({
        src: 'http://www.csszengarden.com/?cssfile=/212/212.css&amp;page=0'
    });
});

$('#v3').click(function() {
    $('#iframetarget').prop({
        src: 'http://www.csszengarden.com/?cssfile=/211/211.css&amp;page=0'
    });
});​
```

This was tested with a fiddle, and it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/sablefoste/DbYPp/1/

Comment: It should.  The magic is in the statement `$.stylesheetSwitch(this.getAttribute('rel'));`, specifically the `getAttribute('re')`.  If your iframe `id='iframetarget'`, then you would do something like `$.stylesheetSwitch($('#iframetarget').getAttribute('rel'));`.  I haven't tested it, but it should work.

Comment: Okay, I added a different strategy of code, it should work for you now.  Really, this is much simpler than my original proposal.

Comment: Actually, this only works with csszengarden.  I tried moving it to my framework and it doesn't move over at all.

Comment: What doesn't work?  What are you seeing?  Can you post a fiddle, or a link to check out?  There is nothing special at all about csszengarden; it is totally standards compliant (that is why I chose it).

Comment: Ok, let's say I want to replicate what you're doing, and I replease the src: with 'http://www.mydomain.com/cssfiles/summer.css' and another with 'fall.css', it doesn't work.  if I keep the csszengardens' files, it shows... the CSS Zen Garden webpage in the iframe.

Comment: csszengarden passes the style with the $_GET variable.  If you are hosting the other website, you can program the server side to do the same.  I don't think it is possible if you can't control the server side code.  If you don't use an iframe, you can follow something like http://www.cssnewbie.com/simple-jquery-stylesheet-switcher/.